# What's the meaning of this usage of Java generics?

Tags: java, generics

I'd like to know what the first `<T>` represents in the following line of Java code.  I've read several tutorials on generics but none of the examples have 2 generics before the method name.  Thanks.

```
public <T> Provider<T> scope(Key<T> key, Provider<T> unscoped);
```

Comment: Yes,I also don't understand generic in method signature.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first `<T>` is the actual type parameter declaration, i.e. it says that the method is generic and has a type parameter `T`.

The second `<T>` is simply part of the method's return type, i.e. the method returns a `Provider<T>`.

If the first `<T>` were omitted, the return type `Provider<T>` would be invalid, since `T` would not be a recognised identifier/name for a type. `T` is only recognised as a type because the first `<T>` introduces it as such.

Comment: still i don't know benefit of first <T> in method signature.

Comment: So if the method used more than one type parameter, say T2, would it look like this? `public <T> <T2> Provider<T> scope(Key<T> key, Provider<T> unscoped, <T2> something);`

Comment: No. It would look like `public <T, T2> Provider<T> scope(Key<T> key, Provider<T> unscoped, T2 something);`